# pip installコマンドでCould not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:というエラーが出る

Tags: python

[Cola](https://github.com/chineking/cola)というプログラムを使って、Weiboの投稿を取得したいです。
`pip install cola`まではうまくいきますが
下記のコマンドを打つとエラーが表示されます。
エラーがなぜ起きるかわかる方がいれば教えてください。

```
 [root@localhost デスクトップ]# pip install -r/path/to/cola/app/weibo/requirements.txt
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/cola/app/weibo/requirements.txt'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ファイルが存在しないと言っているようです。
今一度その場所にファイルがあるかどうか確かめてください。

Comment: pipは`-r`の後ろにスペースがあってもなくてもいいみたいです。

Comment: で、/path/to/cola/app/weibo/requirements.txt は存在しているのでしょうか？ /path/to の部分はGitHubから取得し配置した実際のpathに置き換えてください

Comment: @tag1216 あらら、そうだったんですか。これは失礼。